# Lucen/Elasticsearch: a query for a filed with multiple values

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

Here is what I would like to do. I have an index with several documents in Elasticsearch. In every document I have two field: deviceField (name of the device) and pressionField (the value of the pression periodically). I want to query in my index the average pression per device. Do you know a way to do it in a single query? Indeed, I do not want to do a kind of loop 'for' in order to the query per deviceName. It will take too much time due to the fact that I have millions of devices.

Thank you for your attention and your help.

S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use metric aggregations. If you want to list all at same query you use subaggregation

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "devices" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "deviceField" },
             "aggs" : {
                "avg_pression" : { "avg" : { "field" : "pressionField" } }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the link of documentation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-avg-aggregation.html

Comment: Hi Pablo, thank you for your reply. However, I got an error by using your code.            "type" : "search_parse_exception",
      "reason" : "Could not find aggregator type [avg_pression] in [aggs]",.    Do you know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Maybe the subaggregation must be inside the another. I have edited the code. Try now. If the problem persist paste your query to help you.